# Is どうしよう the equivalent of the Chinese 怎么办?

Tags: words

I just learned that doushiyou means ''what shall I do?''

Is this the equivalent of the Chinese 怎么办 ?

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, どうしよう is mostly compatible with 怎么办 when it means "what should ***I*** do?" (often in self-talk). When the Chinese expression tells "what do ***you*** do?", it will be どうする？ or どうしますか？